# Is there any way to make this code more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy

I have to write a code to calculate the number of elements that have the maximum number of divisors between any 2 given numbers (A[0], A[1])(inclusive of both). I have to take input in the form of a line separated with spaces. The first line of the input gives the number of cases present in an example. This code is working perfectly fine but is taking some time to execute. Can anyone please help me write this code more efficiently?

```
import numpy as np
from sys import stdin
t=input()
for i in range(int(t)):
    if int(t)<=100 and int(t)>=1:
        divisor=[]
        A=list(map(int,stdin.readline().split(' ')))
        def divisors(n):
            count=0   
            for k in range(1,int(n/2)+1):
                if n%k==0:
                    count+=1
            return count
        for j in np.arange(A[0],A[1]+1):
            divisor.append(divisors(j))
        print(divisor.count(max(divisor)))
```

Sample input:

```
2
2 9
1 10
```

Sample Output:

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to calculate divisors from the prime factorisation of a number. 
Given the prime factorisation, calculating divisors is faster than trial division (which you do here).

But prime factorisation has to be fast. For small numbers having a pre-calculated list of prime numbers (easy to do) can make prime factorisation fast and divisor calculation fast as well. If you konw the upper limit of the numbers you test (let's call it `L`), then you need the prime numbers up to `sqrt(L)`. Given the prime factorisation of a number `n = p_1^e_1 * p_2^e_2 * .. * p_k^e_k` the [number of divisors is simply `(1+e_1) * (1+e_2) * .. * (1+e_k)`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433848/prime-factors-number-of-divisors)

Even more, you can pre-calculate and/or memoize the num of divisors of some overused numbers up to some limit. This will save a lot of time but increase memory, else you can calculate it directly (for example using previous method).

Apart from that, you can optimise the code a bit. For example you can avoid doing `int(t)` casting (and similar) all the time, do it once and store it in a variable.

`Numpy` may be avoided all together, it is superflous and I doubt adds any speed advantage, depends.

That should make your code faster, but always need to measure performance by real tests.